# Android - Send Email from App crashes Email - Force Close

Tags: java, javascript, android, email

I have an app that triggers an email from Javascript through Java which then attaches a file.

I get the chooser which has "Email" or "Gmail" as my options.

If I select Gmail then the Gmail client opens as expeceted with subject, body, and attachement all there.

But if I choose Email I get: "The application Email (process com.google.android.email) has stopped unexpectedly. Force close." I need it to use corporate email so this is no good.

Log shows: "Caused by: `java.lang.illegalArgumentException`"

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty( "splashscreen", R.drawable.splash );
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 1000);
    JavaScriptInterface jsi = new JavaScriptInterface(this, appView);
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(jsi, "Android");
    }
}
```

JavaScriptInterface

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
private WebView mAppView;
private DroidGap mGap;
public JavaScriptInterface (DroidGap gap, WebView view)
{
    mAppView = view;
    mGap = gap;
    }
public void doEmail(){

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/html");
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"test text");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"test subject");
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("sdcard/test co.html"));
    mGap.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email..."));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you looked at the exception in logcat (`adb logcat`) to give us a hint as to what line on which the issue occurs.

Comment: My guess is it doesn't like the Uri you're passing for `EXTRA_STREAM`.  Did you try putting file:// in from on the filename?

Comment: Wow. That worked! I put `"file:///sdcard/test co.html"` and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'll submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put "file://" in front of your filename.